# every parent in the tree for each child with level for grand parent as 1

Tags: sql, plsql

Lets say we have the following data set.

```
PARENT     CHILD
---------- -----------
S1         S2
S2         S3
S3         S4
S4         S5
S5
```

I'd like list every parent in the tree for each child.
For example,

```
CHILD      PARENT        LEVEL
---------- -----------  ------
S5         S4              4
S5         S3              3
S5         S2              2
S5         S1              1
S4         S3              3
S4         S2              2
S4         S1              1
etc......
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with 
    tbl as (select 'S1' as parent,'S2'  as child from dual union all
                    select 'S2' as parent,'S3'  as child from dual union all
                    select 'S3' as parent,'S4'  as child from dual union all
                    select 'S4' as parent,'S5'  as child from dual union all
                    select 'S5' as parent, null as child from dual)
    ,tree as (select connect_by_root(t.child) r
                                    ,t.child,t.parent
                                    ,level l from tbl t
                        where child is not null
                        connect by  prior parent =child)
select r as "CHILD"
            ,parent  as "PARENT"
            ,max(l) over (partition by r) - l + 1 as "LEVEL"
from tree
where r is not null
order by r desc, l
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/2460)